# Angular JS | Object content cleaned up after pushing another object to array

Tags: angularjs

I build a form that looks like this:

```
$scope.users = {EmpLst : [
    {
        EmpName: "",
        EmpNumber: "",
       ExamResultList: [
    ]
    }
]};
```

and this is my Html code:

```
                      <div ng-repeat="emp in user.EmpLst track by $index">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" ng-hide="viewMode">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <label class="control-label">Emp:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <select ng-disabled="viewMode" name="item90display" ng-model="emp" class="form-control" ng-options="em as em.EmpName for fab in allEmp track by em.EmpNumber">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <ui-select multiple ng-model="emp.ExamResultList" title="Choose a examp" on-select="console.log($item, $model)">
                                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Exam...">{{$item.EmpName}}</ui-select-match>
                                <ui-select-choices repeat="option in allExamResult | propsFilter: {EmpName: $select.search, ExamResult: $select.search}">
                                    <div ng-bind-html="option.EmpName | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                                    <small>
                                        {{option.EmpName}} {{option.ExamResult}}
                                    </small>
                                </ui-select-choices>
                            </ui-select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Each time when clicking Add button I am executing the following method:

```
$scope.AddFabSoldtoEmptyObj = function () {
    $scope.user.EmpLst.push({
        EmpName: "",
        EmpNumber: "",
        ExamResultList: []
    });
}
```

Variable declaration:

```
   $scope.user.EmpLst = [
          {
            EmpName: "",
            EmpNumber: "",
            ExamResultList: []
        }
     ];
```

And then, all the previous values have been deleted, the EmpLst is now contained the same number of objects, but all of them are empty.

What could be the reason for that?

Note, The HTML code is inside a  tag.

Thanks a lot for helpers.

Comment: You are trying to push only the empty values everytime, what do you expect ? Is that your question or ?

Comment: I pushed another object to an existing array, why the previous values have been deleted?

Comment: How and where have you declared your array $scope.user.EmpLst, can you post that

Comment: See my edit. this declaration occurs in the controller.

Comment: Ok. I see your problem. $scope.users is your JSON object and inside that you have an EmpLst as an array. Hence you will have to build the EmpLst array first and then push it this way $scope.user['EmpLst'] = EmpLstArray

Comment: A Simple example for your reference assuming you have the json object declared this way
$scope.user = { Emp: [] };
            var tempArray = [];
            tempArray.push(1);
            tempArray.push(2);
            $scope.user['Emp'] = tempArray;

Comment: Hi, before I making the change I want to ask: why the object 'emp' is bound successfully and the 'user.EmpLst' is not? (has the same count of objects but the values are empty...). u can see that emp is an object of the ng-repeat from user.EmpLst

Comment: I dont follow your question and not sure which 'emp' are you referring your code. Keep it simple. You have an array inside a json. So ensure you populate the array first and finally you assign it to the json object by choosing the element name 'EmpLst'